# listener.d: crashes upon unclean disconnect

Tags: exception, listener, d

For a small chat server thingie I'm making, I decided to use D; finding myself 
with a very neat example from listener.d to get a kick start I decided to 
pretty much take the example over! However, I'm stuck on a bug I can't truly 
wrap my finger around. Most likely it's my own fault and I'm doing something 
wrong, but considering I took the code pretty much from the example I am more 
inclined to believe the example is broken.

I'll explain what happens:

- List item
- I start up my server (nothing wrong, it's running as it should and listening)
- I telnet to it. My server accepts the connection.
- I use telnet to send some information. Server handles the information 
  properly, again, no issue.
- I quit telnet by using ^] and then writing quit. Breaking the connection 
  rather ungracefully.
- The server properly recognises this isn't a clean disconnect and executes 
  the code to remove the socket.
- I then get a range violation.

This is the main process and it's loop: 
https://github.com/JGBrands/BlaatServer/blob/master/source/bserver.d

This is the server class, the code where it deletes the socket is at the 
complete bottom in the function void destroySocket(int index);

https://github.com/JGBrands/BlaatServer/blob/master/source/server.d

Actually let me copy paste that. :-)

```
void destroySocket(int index) {
    this.reads[index].close(); /* release resources. */

    /* Remove the socket now. We don't want this around! It'll crash us! */
    if (index != this.reads.length -1)
        this.reads[index] = this.reads[this.reads.length -1];

    this.reads = this.reads[0 .. this.reads.length -1];
    writeln("Total connections: " ~ to!string(this.reads.length));
}
```

The code is primarily taken over from the listener.d example like I said, the 
error I get is this:

```
core.exception.RangeError@server(61): Range violation 
---------------- 
----------------
```

I'm lead to believe the function is deleting something it shouldn't, for those 
interested, this is line 61 in server.d:

```
if (this.sset.isSet(this.reads[i])) {
```

Hopefully you guys can help me make more sense about this, am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: have you investigated what the value of i will be. I see only a check for `i == reads.length` not for any other possible out of bounds

Comment: I solved my own question. See line 60, it should be: ' if (i >= this.reads.length) return false; ' :D

Comment: Edit your question if you can and post an answer.  Narrow down your question; you can't expect people to go through the entire source code.

Comment: @JesseBrands No offense, but it sounds to me like ratchet freak solved your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ratchet points out:

```
if (index != this.reads.length -1)
```

This does not verify that index is within range. It only validates that index is not the last element. This is fine as long as index has already been verified to be within range.

```
void destroySocket(int index)
in {
    assert(index > -1);
    assert(index < this.reads.length);
} body {
{
```

Comment: I asked this a long time ago, and finally someone answers. This is long solved of course, but at now I can finally check an answer.

Comment: @JesseBrands, was my intent. Was going over unanswered questions.